# Vim in Windows command line is seeing deleted files while gVim is not

Tags: windows, powershell, vim, cmd

The directory under concern here is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim`, and the file under concern is a copy of `_vimrc`.

The system is Windows 10.  Same behavior under `cmd.exe` and `Powershell`.  The `vim` version is 7.4.

---

I created a text file under a directory, let's say it has a filename "xxx", then I deleted this file.  The command `DIR` (or `LS` under Powershell) shows that the file is deleted, and `del xxx` or `rm xxx` also report that "xxx does not exist".

However, under command line `vim` is still able to see this file in the same directory, while `gvim` does not see this file.  Namely, `vim xxx` will display the original content, while `gvim xxx` will say that the file xxx does not exist and will create a new one.

`vim .` also shows that the deleted file still exists, while `gvim .` shows the opposite.

Strangely, when running the command line as administrator, both `vim` and `gvim` won't see the file, and `vim .` also shows that the deleted file is not there.

---

It seems similar behavior appears in all the "system directories".  Namely, if I use `vim` (command line; non-admin) to create a new file under a system directory, that file will not show up with the `DIR` or `LS` command, and `gvim` will not see it, but `vim` will be able to see and modify it.

Comment: If one of the programs is a 32bit process and the other is a 64bit process, each one could be reading a different folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the the problem is due to the virtualization mechanism of Windows.

When a non-admin user is trying to create a file under the system folder, Windows will silently redirect the file to a directory local to that user, which is under 
`C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\`, and that file will behave as if it is under the intended directory.

See http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/folder-virtualization-concepts-windows-vista